# Redirect site page on Intel XDK

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, intel

I created an app on Intel XDK and when loaded it redirect to my web site:

```
window.location.href = "http://mysite.com.br";
```

or

```
window.location.replace("http://mysite.com.br");
```

works well on Emulate, however, when compiled android opens the browser with the link from my website.
I need the site to be open within my application.
I know this is possible (or was), because I have older applications that this code works as I wish

Comment: I found answer, on the new version Intel XDK you must define in "Build Settings" -> White list -> Navigation(<allow-navigation>) your website link.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `window.location.assign()` if you want to keep your browser's history

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var url = "http://google.com";
window.open(url, '_system');
```

Tested on android and IOS.